# Where have I to put the jar file containing a WSO2 ESB custom message processor into my WSO2 EI installation?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am pretty new in **WSO2 EI** and I am trying to develop a **custom message processor** that I have to use into the **ESB** flow.

At this time I have only exteded the **SamplingProcessor** class, this one: https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/message/processor/impl/sampler/SamplingProcessor.java

into a Maven project.

I am trying with a minimalistic scenario where I only override the **setParameters()** method inserting a simple log, this is my code:

```
package com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor;
import org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessor;

public abstract class SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation extends SamplingProcessor {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ScheduledMessageProcessor.class.getName());


    @Override
    public void setParameters(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        logger.info("setParameters() START");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setParameters(parameters);

        logger.info("setParameters() END");
    }
}
```

I create the jar file containing the compiled version of thi class using Maven.

My doubt is: where have I to put the generated **SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** file into my **WSO2 EI 6.0.0** installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the JAR file in the `lib` directory of WSO2 EI.

```
<EI_HOME>/lib
```

Another Option:

The artifacts can also be updoaded through the admin console. Refer the following link
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Uploading+Artifacts

Answer (score 1):

You should put it in wso2ei-6.0.0\lib. Then, you should be able to reference it in your XML as com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor.SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation.

However, I believe you cannot make it an abstract class as doing so will prevent WSO2 from instantiating it. So you should remove the 'abstract' keyword from your class.